# C#: Difference between downloading speed

Tags: c#, filesystems

I'm downloading file with console app from remote disk using `StreamReader`:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(sourcePath), 
FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), Encoding.GetEncoding(1251), true)
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        sr.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Everything is fine, but when I'm downloading same file by OS filesystem interface, speed is much more faster then with `StreamReader`.

Can anybody explain how to increase downloading speed for `StreamReader`, if possible?

Comment: I'm not copying file, just reading

Comment: All you need is a FileStream then. Do large reads into a static buffer, 8K or more bytes at a time.

Comment: @glenebob but `FileStream` object has no `ReadLine` method that I'm using

Comment: What's the point of the ReadLine()? In your example, you're throwing away the result.

Comment: @glenebob point is parse file by line to DataTable object and writing it to database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the only way to speed up downloading it is increase buffer size - the bigger, the faster:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sourcePath, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251), true, 8 * 1024 * 1024)
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        sr.ReadLine();
    }
}
```